# Why do I receive "Cannot invoke a rollback operation when the AutoCommit mode is set to "true".", when I did not execute a rollback?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, ibatis

Executing the following results in the exception "Cannot invoke a rollback operation when the AutoCommit mode is set to "true".

```
java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
com.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner scriptRunner = new ScriptRunner(connection, true, true);
java.io.StringReader reader = new StringReader("PRINT 1;");
scriptRunner.runScript(reader);
// Cannot invoke a rollback operation when the AutoCommit mode is set to "true".
```

There is no rollback referenced in my code, and I can find no option to disable it from being forced on me. I have looked through standalone.xml and tried setting jta=false. I found and set commitRequired=false, it was true, on sqlMapConfig\transactionManager, but that did not make a difference.

If the answer to this exists out there, I was not able to find it. All I find is someone saying "of course you cant rollback", and the result being to disable autocommit. I am not asking for a rollback, so where is it coming from?
Per https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner example 3, what I am doing should work.

I want to execute a script in autocommit mode (the default MS SQL Server mode) without any transactions being involved or forced on me, except the autocommit transaction that surrounds each individual statement in the sql script. I do not want IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON, no BEGIN TRANSACTION, no COMMIT, and definitely no ROLLBACK.

Thank you for your time

**Stack Trace:**

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot invoke a rollback operation when the AutoCommit mode is set to "true".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.rollback(SQLServerConnection.java:2037)
    at com.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.java:222)
    at com.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.java:114)
    at com.metric.DebugTests.DebugAutoCommit(DebugTests.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Show the full stacktrace. There's probably an error and ibatis tries to rollback, which is the sane thing to do.

Comment: I added the stacktrace.

Comment: Yup, see there how `ScriptRunner.java:222` is calling rollback. However if there's an underlying exception, this might shadow it and you don't know what's really wrong. You could see if you can configure `ScriptRunner` not to attempt rollback.

Comment: According to https://github.com/mybatis/ibatis-2/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ibatis/common/jdbc/ScriptRunner.java, conn.rollback(); is in the finally, without a check to disable it. Looks like its a different version, but it is informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a quick glance at [ScriptRunner](https://github.com/mybatis/ibatis-2/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ibatis/common/jdbc/ScriptRunner.java) (not the exact version in the question, but close enough), we can see the following code

```
if (!autoCommit) {
    conn.commit();
}
```

Now that's good, we only commit if autocommit isn't on. However, if an exception is thrown, the finally clause is executed and autocommit isn't considered:

```
} finally {
  conn.rollback();
  flush();
}
```

This will result in the losing of the original exception details.

Since the exception does print logs if a logger is set, I recommend doing something like:

```
scriptRunner.setErrorLogWriter(somePrintWriter); // Some PrintWriter, maybe to a file
```

That way you'll find out the original exception. This is also definitely a bug, so it needs to be reported (seems I don't have github credentials, so someone that has those could put up an issue (or hey, why not submit a pull request)).

Comment: Even if there is no exception, the finally runs. I will add the logger like you suggested to see if there is one. Either way the rollback in the finally needs to have more logic around it. Unfortunately this doesn't help me for my task, but at least I know why now. Thank you

Comment: @Russ ah yeas of course, so there might not be an underlying exception (which is of course good). Which version are you using btw, it seems that ibatis2 is outdated. You might want to try the latest version. This bug is fixed in [mybatis-3](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/jdbc/ScriptRunner.java).

Comment: We are using ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar. I believe we are working on migrating to mybatis. I will have to check if it has the same issue, hopefully not. If not then moving sooner than later may be the answer. I was able to verify that no error is occurring.

Answer (score -1):

If you are setting auto commit off then you are responsible for saving you work on database so after every successful task you have to execute a commit command,
To set autocommit off use `connection.setAutoCommit(false)`
and when your work is finished then execute 
`connection.commit()` to save changes to database
or in case of any error execute a rollback command `connection.rollback()` 
Hope It Hepls !!